# Mirrorless camera: setting the diaphragm

Tags: mirrorless

Do mirrorless (hybrid) cameras like the Sony NEX-x or the Panasonic Lumix GFx let you set manually the diaphragm?

Comment: Did you check either manual or look at one of the thousands of reviews online for either model?

Answer (score 2):

**Yes.** Every single mirrorless ever made offers full-manual controls. Some just hide them better than others! Having a mode-dial also helps to quickly set the camera into Aperture priority mode. Fuji lenses for mirrorless cameras all have an aperture ring right on the lens which makes things very easy.

If you are keen on using semi-automatic (A/S/T) or manual (M) modes, I suggest you look for a camera with at least one *control-dial*. [Two is better](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=sld&commanddials=2) if you use Manual mode as there is nothing to press to toggle between both parameters. Some mirrorless cameras even have [three control-dials](http://www.neocamera.com/search_camera.php?size=sld&commanddials=3:min).

Comment: Hey, doesn't the OM-D have 3? 1 for mode, 2 for aperture/shutter?

Comment: That would be one *Mode-Dial* and two *Control-Dials*. There are lots of variants too as some camera do not need mode-dials (as opposed to need one but not have one) and others need two controls per parameter!